# Are ifstream and ofstream non-standard c++ headers?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ifstream, ofstream

Ok, so I was coding a C++ console app involving File - IO. In c++, to apply file io, you have the import one of three headers, them being `<ifstream>`,`<ofstream>`, and `<fstream>`. In Visual Studio Community 2015, at first when I wrote this code:

```
#include <ifstream>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream inf("testingifstream.txt");
}
```

The first thing I noticed right away, is that the Intellisense gave me an error stating that it had an error opening ifstream, as it "was not found". After posting on a different forum, I got the solution to use the `<fstream>` header, since it has the classes for ifstream and ofstream, and then my code worked. But I only need the ifstream class, so I think it is unnecessary that I have to bring fstream in as well. This leads me to my question, are ifstream and ofstream non-standard headers for Windows Visual Studio, and is there any way I can include them?

Comment: There is no separation of them; they are all in the <fstream> header. Also, the compiler won't link in code that you don't use.

Comment: "Intellisense gave me an error" - IntelliSense is *not* the compiler. It is an entirely separate parser with its own bugs and standard compliance issues - use it as a guideline, nothing more.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I didn't know how you get a red sguiggly line under the code if something is not found, so I, to be wrong assumed it was Intellisense.

Comment: Did you get the idea about `ifstream` and `ofstream` headers from MSDN docs (ie., is there a bad example or bad docs)?  MS should fix that if so.

Comment: No, actually, I was reading a tutorial on c++ file - io from [learncpp](http://www.learncpp.com), but it didn't specify anything about Windows not having the headers.

Comment: Look at my answer in the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the only standard header is `<fstream>`, containing both `ifstream`and `ofstream` classes (and `fstream` of course).

> [17.6.1.2] The C++ standard library provides 55 C++ library headers, as shown in Table 14.

In the table, there is no `<ifstream>`or `<ofstream>`.

Answer (score 1):

The headers are nonstandard for windows. You can't include them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The headers are non-standard period, not just for Windows (gcc also doesn't include them)